# Как декодировать знак вопроса в ссылке?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть два `radio`:
`input type="checkbox" value="site.ru/article` и `input type="checkbox" value="?start=1`.
Также есть JS-скрипт, который при нажатии двух `radio` берёт их значения и формирует их них ссылку, выполняет переход по данной ссылке.

Но есть проблема: вопросительный знак при этом превращается в нечто `%3F`. Подскажите, как решить проблему?

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']").forEach(el => el.checked=false);
let letters = [];

const itemList = [];

document.querySelectorAll('.productdetaiils li').forEach((el, i) => {

  const letter = el.innerText.trim().split(' ')[0][0];

  letters.push(letter);

  letters = [...new Set(letters)];

  itemList.push({
    id: i,
    content: el.innerHTML,
    letter
  });

  const lettersMap = letters.map(el => {
    return `<label class="example-lk"><input class="downers form-check-input" name="b" type="radio" value=${el} autocomplete="off">${el}</label>`
  });

  document.querySelector('.results .tabs').innerHTML = lettersMap.join('')

});

document.querySelectorAll('.tabs input').forEach(tab => {
  tab.onclick = (e) => {
    if(tab.name!=="b") return;
    const FilteredList = itemList.filter(item => item.letter === e.target.value).map(item => `<li>${item.content}</li>`);

    document.querySelector('.results .content').innerHTML = FilteredList

    e.target.closest(".results").querySelector(".content").classList.add("show");

    const pd = document.querySelector(".productdetails")
    if (pd) {
      pd.remove()
    }
  }



});

/////////

let data = {
  a: null,
  c: null
}

document.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
  const input = event.target.closest("input");
  if (!input || input.getAttribute("type") !== "radio") return;

  let name = input.name;
  if (!name || !data.hasOwnProperty(name)) return;

  if (!input.checked) {
    data[name] = null;
    return;
  }

  data[name] = input.value;
  if (name === "a") {
    // если какое-то значение не выбрано
    if (Object.values(data).some(v => !v)) return;

    location.pathname = data.a + data.c;
  }
  if (name === "c") {
    // если какое-то значение не выбрано
    if (Object.values(data).some(v => !v)) return;

    location.pathname = data.a + data.c;

  }
});
```

```css
.productdetaiils {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-stage">
  <div class="rower">
    <h3 class="frst-rep-ttl">Выберите неисправность устройства:</h3>
    <div class="fix-item first-check">
      <input autocomplete="off" id="link1" class="linkinp form-check-input" name="c" type="radio" value="?start=1">Ссылка 1

    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<ul class="productdetaiils">
  <li>
    <div class="entry-image intro-image">
      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="/all/laptops/acer/aspire-r-13-r7-372t-520q" name="a"> Сслыка 2
      </li>
</ul>
<div class="results">
    <ul class="tabs"> </ul>
    <ul class="content"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Comment: @InDevX пробовал, почему-то не срабатывает. Возможно, я неправильно указал данное значение `if (Object.values(data).some(v => !v)) return; data.a = decodeURIComponent('%3F');location.pathname = data.a + data.c;`

Comment: полностью ссылку оберните

Comment: @InDevX выше отправил. Полдня пытаюсь по-разному, уже запутался, если честно)

Comment: @InDevX проблема в том, что я предоставил минифицированный код. Там идут дальше чекбоксы с `?start=1`, `?start=2`, `?start=3` итд

Comment: Проблема в location.pathname, он преобразовывает символ. Используйте тот же location.href и не нужно ничего менять в вашем коде проблемы не будет